# Obtener nombre de carpeta actual con expresiones regulares

Tags: jscript

Estoy queriendo mostrar el nombre de la carpeta en la que me encuentro, en un control de un diálogo, para ello he escrito las siguientes líneas, pero no funciona, me informa de un error en la línea del RegExp.

```javascript
var ruta = item.path; //Ejemplo: D:\Test\Final
var carpeta_actual = ruta.replace(/(.*)(\\)(.*)$/,"$3"); //Resultado esperado: Final
dlg.Control("album").value = carpeta_actual;
```

Comment: *me informa de un error en la línea del RegExp* Bien, ¿podrías decirnos cuál ese error que te informa? Porque, aunque tengamos toda la intención de ayudarte, no somos adivinos. Por otro lado, IMHO, usar una RegExp para esto me parece excesivo.

Comment: No informé sobre el tipo de error porque el explorador de archivos tampoco lo hace, solo dice error en el procesamiento de la línea del  RegExp, por lo visto no estoy sabiendo establecer bien el RegExp, y he usado RegExp porque no he sabido usar otro método, con `Split()` por ejemplo,  sabría dividir la cadena en cada `\\`, pero no sabría como obtener el último fragmento pues estos siempre varían, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta obtenida fuera de aquí fue:

```
var carpeta_actual = item.realpath.pathpart.match(/.*\\(.*)/)[1]);
```